# Python/PySide6: Apply different style to sub class

Tags: python, pyside6

Cant figure out the solution of the problem.
The style of the sub class is identical to the base class:

```
import sys
from PySide6.QtGui import *
from PySide6.QtWidgets import *
from PySide6.QtCore import *

class MyLabel(QLabel):
    def __init__(self, pText: str) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.setText(pText)
        
class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        self.setFixedWidth(200)
        self.setFixedHeight(200)

        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.widget = QLabel("QLabel")
        layout.addWidget(self.widget)

        self.mywidget = MyLabel("MyLabel")
        layout.addWidget(self.mywidget)
        self.setLayout(layout)

        stylesheet = ("""
            MyLabel {
                border: 20px solid black;
            }
            QLabel {
                border: 20px solid red;
            }
            """
        )
        self.setStyleSheet(stylesheet)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = MainWindow()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

The expectation is to have the inherited label in a different color.
Eg MyLabel should be black. QLabel should be red.
Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Had a typo in the shown py-script:
self.widget and self.mywidget were  instances of MyLabel class.
This is fixed.
Figured out that it depends on the sequence of styles:
This sequence does not work:

```
        stylesheet = ("""
            MyLabel {
                border: 20px solid black;
            }
            QLabel {
                border: 20px solid red;
            }
            """
        )
```

This sequence works:

```
        stylesheet = ("""
            QLabel {
                border: 20px solid red;
            }
            MyLabel {
                border: 20px solid black;
            }
            """
        )
```

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/stylesheet-syntax.html#conflict-resolution